# Load Item with delay in FlatList in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have integrate the FlatList, I want to put delay 1000 ml to load the each item. At first load the index 0, after 1000 ml load the index 1...

It's possible to delay in the FlatList item.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a perfect solution to this, I will try to write an expo snack for you

Comment: @Sarmad okay send me snack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i came up with,

It isn't perfect, but it should do your job.

Basically I calculated your index and multiplied it with `1000`, and that number, I set a timeout in the `Item` Component

https://snack.expo.io/@azaabudeen/authentic-beef-jerky

```
    const data = [
  {name: 'name1'},
  {name: 'name2'},
  {name: 'name3'},
  {name: 'name4'},
  {name: 'name5'},
  {name: 'name6'},
  {name: 'name7'},
]
class Item extends React.Component {
  state = { loading: true }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ loading: false }), this.props.time);
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.loading) {
      return null;
    }
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.data.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default class App extends React.Component {
  renderItem=({ item, index}) => {
    return(
      <Item time={index * 1000} data={item}/>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList 
        data={data}
        initialNumToRender={0}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
       />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

});
```

Comment: I want to delay with each individual items. Like to item0 after putting delay adn after items1... Like that.

Comment: I think that's what this is? Every item renders after i second gap, Did you try the snack?

Comment: Yes. I want gap between two item.

Comment: According your code it's gap dalay only first time.

Comment: "Yes. I want gap between two item.", Please run my code. It will do exactly that.